# What part of Tiger & Bunny do purple, white, and green plastic bins refer to?

Tags: tiger-and-bunny

In an article I read recently, entitled ["Images That Do Not Make Any Sense If You Are Not A Fan"](http://www.crunchyroll.com/anime-news/2013/04/05/images-that-do-not-make-any-sense-if-you-are-not-a-fan), about a [Twitter hash](https://twitter.com/search?q=%23%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%90%E3%83%8B%E3%82%AF%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E4%BB%A5%E5%A4%96%E3%81%8C%E8%A6%8B%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89%E6%84%8F%E5%91%B3%E4%B8%8D%E6%98%8E%E3%81%AA%E7%94%BB%E5%83%8F%E8%BC%89%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B&src=hash) that is currently trending, there was an image of a bunch of color-coordinated plastic bins:

[image]

The article seems to suggest that this image is somehow related to *Tiger & Bunny*. What part of the anime are these bins referencing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's related to the color-coordination of each superhero's costume. Each characters has a color they identify with:

[image: The colors, dude]

Barnaby Brooks Jr., a.k.a. "Bunny" is White (with Red).

[image: Bunny]

Kotetsu T. Kaburagi, a.k.a. "Wild Tiger" is Yellow (with White and Green).

[image: Wild Tiger]

Antonio Lopez, a.k.a. "Rock Bison" is Green.

Yuri Petrov, a villain known as "Lunatic," is Black.

Side note: the fried rice is a reference to how Bunny finally learns how to make fried rice (Kotetsu's favorite food).